# Tax rule for different states in India

Tags: magento, tax

I m trying to add tax rules in my store for India region.
In India, we have two tax rates.

1) VAT @ 5% for the goods sold within the state.
2) CST @ 5% for the goods sold outside the state.

I managed to add VAT @ 5%. But I m unable to add the CST @ 5%. 
I need to create CST tax for other states. For one state I was able to add tax but for other states when I add, it shows the error as CODE ALREADY EXISTS.

Example.
I created the Tax identifier: VAT @ 5%
Country: India
State: Tamil Nadu
Rate Percent: 5

Now I created the Tax Identifier: CST @ 5%
Country: India
State: Punjab
Rate Percent: 5
This applies CST @ 5% only for the state of Punjab.

Now when I try to create tax for the other states, for example, Kerala, it shows the error " code already exists"

How can I group all the states other than Tamil Nadu in the Tax Identifier CST @ 5%?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need exact Tax Identifier CST @ 5% for each of CST 5% percent region. Just add a state name to the given Tax Identifier.

For example "CST @ 5%" for the Tamil Nadu state will becpme "CST @ 5% Tamil Nadu". Then you will not see the "code already exists" error.